# ES6 imports, exports = Error: invalid argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

i have this setup

file1.js:

```
export function foo1() { ... };
```

file2.js:

```
export function foo2() { ... }
```

hook.js:

```
 import {foo1} from './file1';
 import {foo2} from './file2';

 export {foo1, foo2};
```

Now when i want to import from my hook:

app.js

```
import { foo1 } from '../data/hook.js';
```

i get this:

```
Error: invalid argument
```

When calling foo1. (The function has no arguments/parameters).

Anyone know what's the problem?

**UPDATE:**

I also get the `invalid argument`when importing foo1 directly from file1.
Is this a Babel Problem?

My .babelrcb( i use test as environment):

```
"env": {
  "targets": {
    "node": "4.8.4"
  },
  "test": {
    "presets": ["env"]
  },
}
```

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

It turned out the import was correct, thx for all the guys who helped me on this Q. The problem was due to a Promise inside the function foo1 which caused the import to fail:

```
browser.waitUntil(..); // see http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitUntil.html
```

Comment: `function foo1();` is a syntax error. Did you mean `function foo1() {}`?

Comment: yeah sure i have a full function, see update, that's what it looks like

Comment: Can you try reproducing it using a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `./` in import and `default` in the export

#### File1.js

`export default function foo1()`

#### hook.js

`import {foo1} from './File1'`

otherwise, it will search for File1 in *node_modules*

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: ah yes i have it like this in my hook. as well as in the module that imports from  the hook

Comment: with `default`i am getting `TypeError: (0 , _file1.foo) is not a function
`

Comment: there must some other error, will you please post the complete code of your function.

Comment: You are absolutely right my friend, the function uses a promise: browser.waituntil(..) this must be the reason why the import fails.

Answer (score 1):

Function body is missing on file1 and file2.

file1.js:

```
export function foo1() {};
```

file2.js:

```
export function foo2() {};
```

On hook.js, you should export default.

```
import {foo1} from './file1';
import {foo2} from './file2';

export default {foo1, foo2};
```